# How to generate ETag for HTML (full page) content in Varnish?

Tags: varnish, etags

I want to configure Varnish to generate ETag of HTML requested content (maybe with MD5 of HTML and "Vary" headers) and to deal with 304 and If-None-Match headers.

Is this possible with configuration or vlc scripting?

Answer (score 1):

For ETags to work your backend need to generate the correct Etags along with the content. If the Etags are present Varnish will use them.